# unexpected braces in my NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i am adding `NSDictionary` of phone numbers to `NSMutableArray` like this:

```
NSMutableArray *main_level = [NSMutableArray array];


[main_level addObject:@{@"phone":@[@"052443223",@"763765347647",@"763765347647",@"763765347647",@"763765347647",@"763765347647",@"763765347647"]}];
```

this is what the log prints :

```
2013-10-14 10:49:27.544 tfv[44111:907] (
    {
    phone =         (
        052443223,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647
    );
}
)
```

but the expected result is without the braces like so :
when i am logging this `NSLog(@"%@",[main_level objectAtIndex:0]);`

```
2013-10-14 10:50:22.539 tfv[44129:907] {
phone =     (
    052443223,
    763765347647,
    763765347647,
    763765347647,
    763765347647,
    763765347647,
    763765347647
);
```

}

why does this braces added and how can i avoid it?

Comment: The first is logging an array containing a dictionary containing an array.  The second is logging a dictionary containing an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are adding an array of phone numbers into dictionary with key = phone.

2) Then you are adding that dictionary to array.

So, whatever the **output is correct**. You just **can not avoid that braces**.

If you want to get the first phone number , then do this,

```
NSDictionary *dictOfPhoneNumbers = [[main_level objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"phone"];

for(int i=0; i<dictOfPhoneNumbers.count; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"Phone = %@",[dictOfPhoneNumbers objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
( <-- beginning of array
    { <-- beginning of dictionary
    phone =         ( <-- beginning of phone array
        052443223,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647,
        763765347647
        ); <-- end of phone array
    } <-- end if dictionary
) <-- end of array
```

It just means you are printing an array. i.e. `NSLog(@"%@",main_level);`

If you do `NSLog(@"%@",[main_level objectAtIndex:0]);` then you are printing a dictionary.